# datepicker time is not equal how to fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, time, datepicker

`todayDateTime` displays the correct time, but `startDateTest` displays the incorrect time. It has added 7 hours. I want it to display the correct time without me subtracting the hours.

```js
function setDatePicker() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();

  success: function(data) {
    var todayDateTime = eval(data.date.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"));
    var todayDate = eval(data.date.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"));
    todayDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    var newDateObj = new Date();
    var n = todayDateTime.getHours();
    if (n < 7) {
      todayDateTime.setHours(7, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    newDateObj.setTime(todayDateTime.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));

    $('#dpVBH_START_DATE').datepicker({
      autoclose: true
    });
    $("#dpVBH_START_DATE").datepicker("setDate", todayDateTime);
    $("#dpVBH_START_TIME").data("kendoTimePicker").value(todayDateTime);
    $('#dpVBH_FINISH_DATE').datepicker({
      autoclose: true
    });
    $("#dpVBH_FINISH_DATE").datepicker("setDate", newDateObj);
    $("#dpVBH_FINISH_TIME").data("kendoTimePicker").value(newDateObj);

    var startdatetest = $("#dpvbh_start_date").data('datepicker').date;
    console.log("startDateTest", startDateTest);
    console.log("todayDateTime", todayDateTime);
    console.log("todayDate", todayDate);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: `function setDatePicker() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();

  success: function(data) {` is not valid JS, please create a running example

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a good reason for using jQuery (which is obsolete now, it's 2023...c'mon) with a jQuery-based datepicker instead of just using HTML's `<input type="datetime-local">` ?